# Maximo Object Structure as API: MXASSET OS reduce response to necessary ASSETSPEC data

Tags: json, api, maximo

To cut straight to the issue - We have data elements in AssetSpec that are needed in order to report data on and would like to have exposed as an API for consumption.  The amount of Asset Records are not that much especially when only reducing the columns to assetnum and description (~1600 records).  The problem comes into play when pulling data back from AssetSpec where it blows the payload out of the water.  We only need a couple of data points from assetspec, but because the data element names and values are themselves "Data" I'm not sure how to only retrieve only those 4 from the list of 25.  In the request we are able to filter based on the data, however it doesn't reduce the response to only those data points from AssetSpec, we can only reduced based on the column names and not the data within them.  I'm hoping there is a way to do it or will this have to be some sort of transformation applied to the object structure?

example of request on MXASSET OS.

```
{{domainAPI}}os/mxasset?lean=1&oslc.select=assetnum,description,siteid,status, ASSETSPEC{ASSETATTRID, ALNVALUE}&oslc.paging=FALSE&oslc.where=classstructureid=#### AND ASSETSPECCLASS.assetattrid="IT.MODELTYPE" AND ASSETSPECCLASS.alnvalue in ["Laptop","Desktop","PANASONIC TOUGHBOOK","SURFACE PRO"]
```

The four data points I'd like to be used in the response is NAME, IT.Model, IT.Modeltype, IT.OS

I could leverage the pagination in order to chop it up, however the primary problem through the assetspec table is we are getting way more data then what is required.

Any solutions or thoughts to get me pointed in the right direction would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own ASSET OS (ex.: ASSET_COMPUTER) with a custom relationship to the ASSETSPEC object (ex.: COMPUTER_SPEC) where you filter on only the required attributes.

```
assetnum=:assetnum and siteid=:siteid and assetattrid in ('NAME','MODEL','ETC')
```